# How to use a simple timeout with Rx .NET / Dispose needed?

Tags: .net, timer, system.reactive

What is the most simple way to raise a fire and forget callback after 3 seconds with Rx .NET. I noticed this works, but do I have to dispose it or something? Im not sure.

```
Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)).Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("Fired"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is it, I would mark your question as an answer if I could ;).

Regarding disposal, you usually need to dispose the subscription if:

- you're subscribing to an observable that belongs to a container with longer life span than the subscribing component.
- you need to "unsubscribe" early.

Your sample is not one of these, so don't worry about unsubscribing.

Comment: Great! So this looks as if Rx makes .NET timers first class citizens!

Comment: Still, using .Timer() is something you do not use too often in RX. The reason is that timeout is an arbitrary value, while RX provides other alternatives to wait till some action can be performed.

Comment: Im just scratching the surface. However, I was just looking for an alternative to System.Timer or System.Threading.Timer. Since I'm doing a lot work in JavaScript lately I was missing something super easy as setTimeout(new function(){console.log('Fired');}, 3000); in .NET. For sure, I know that Rx is far more than that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just for kicks, here's another alternative that uses Rx but puts the scheduler front and centre and omits the subscription business and the unnecessary argument on the Action. As before you could use the returned `IDisposable` to cancel the action.:

```
Scheduler.Default.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), () => Console.WriteLine("Fired"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just curious, but your question says 'timeout', not 'timer'. What you have is an event that occurs at the given time, not a wait on an event gives up after a given time. While it seems you are happy with the answer, I thought I would check for clarity.

To do the later, you can add a .Timeout(Timespan) to an observable sequence. As James World has mentioned, there is a Scheduler at play here implicitly. While you keep the Scheduler implicit you will find unit-testing a pain. Ideally you should provide the Scheduler you want to use to the Timer/Interval/Timeout method you use.

Comment: I changed it from `timeout` to `callback`. Should be clearer. Anyway, thanks for the extra info.